# Need to show *ngIf directive element in UI only after API response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have a validation API and based on the error, I'm highlighting the field, but before validation is completed it is showing no errors only. How can restrict it.

My HTML-

```
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell style="max-width: 6%;" *matCellDef="let element; let i=index">
                    <button *ngIf="!element.HAS_ERROR" mat-icon-button>
                        <span class="material-icons" style="color: #55bd55;">done</span>
                    </button>// this element is showing till before validation API response. but I need to restrict till API response.
                  
                    <button mat-icon-button color="warn" *ngIf="element.HAS_ERROR" (click)="openConflictDialog(i)">
                        <span class="material-icons">
                          info
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

TS-

```
 asyncReq(element:any){
      this.conflictData = null;
        //For all day
        let startDate:any;
        let endDate:any;
        startDate = this.easternToUtc.transform(moment(element.START_TIME).format('YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00'), this.selectedTimeZone);
        endDate =  this.easternToUtc.transform(moment(element.END_TIME).format('YYYY/MM/DD 23:59:59'), this.selectedTimeZone);
      return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        let requestPayload = zipObj(['USER_ID','AMENITY_TYPE_ID','AMENITY_ID','START_TIME', 'END_TIME', 'BUILDING_ID', 'AMENITY_NAME'],
        [element.USER_ID,element.AMENITY_TYPE_ID,element.AMENITY_ID,startDate,
          endDate, element.BUILDING_ID, element.AMENITY_NAME]);
        this.http.post(`${environment.reservationValidation}`, requestPayload).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(e => {
          }, (e:any) => {
            console.log(e);
            element.ERROR_TYPE = e.error?.message;
            element.HAS_ERROR = true;
            this.conflictData = e.error?.reservationdata;
          })
        })
    }
```

Comment: You can set one flag after response which is initially false and use that flag in *ngIf

Comment: @Vinay Can you add some example of that flag

Comment: can you add api call code in question?

Answer (score 1):

Check this example.
[Stackblitz NgIf Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-pipe-with-ngif-and-as-zmdvbj?file=app/app.component.ts)

First set an Observable and subject and call it with async pipe in html file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simply take one global boolean type variable in .ts file, after getting the successful API response, based on whatever the key is needed from response, we can make our variable to true. You can use this variable in your *ngIf directive to make it visible or hidden.